# Less :extend. Is it possible to extend classes from another file?

Tags: html, less

I have two files. both less files. they have a section of code that is identical and I am wondering if it is possible to import just a specific class and its children from one file to another.

Here would be an example

file one:

```
<div>
  <div class="first">
    <div class="first-identical"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

file two:

```
<div>
  <div class="second">        
    <div class="second-identical"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each of these files have separate .less files for their styling. I am trying to see if I can import the contents of 'identical' into file two's less file so I don't have the style code in two separate places.

```
.first {
  &-identical {
    // defined styles
  }
}
```

I have tried ':extend(.identical all)' in file two's less file but wasn't seeing the styles come through. This is an example of what I've tried.

```
.second {
  &:extend('.identical all')
}
```

Wondering if I need to import file one's less file in some way or what needs to change if this is possible?